# Bootstrap-Select plugin not working with time consuming page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap select plugin of silviomoreto. I am using it in an ASP.Net MVC application.
I am using this with show tick option. The code is like this.

```
setTimeout(function () {
     $('#ddlSortBy').selectpicker({
                'selectedText': 'Select'                   
                }
            });

        }, 200);
```

The problem is that this plug is not working without settimeout method in my application. I have to attach this plugin within settimeout method and within document.ready method.

However some time when a page loading takes more that 200 ms what I find that plugin is applied to html select but clicking on item in select is not working. So I have to increase the timeout of to attach then its works. But ideally it should works once attached to a html select element.

Comment: Try attaching your function to a `$(document).ready()` event or a mutation observer, depending on how `#ddlSortBy` is being injected into the page. It's never a good idea to pick a magic number for `setTimeout` to wait for something to appear on the page.

Comment: Palpatim, Thanks for replying. But I am already using $(document).ready() event. I am using setTimeout within ready event. Thanks for your suggestion.