# Bootsrap-select retains default options inside SetTimeout call

Tags: javascript, settimeout, bootstrap-select

I am initializing a bootstrap-select control successfully on document.ready, but if I put it inside a setTimeout, all my options are ignored and the default options are used instead.  I have tried debugging through the selectpicker js code but I can't figure out why this behavior is different.  Please note I did see a very similar question but it was never successfully answered ([Bootstrap-Select plugin not working with time consuming page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580074/bootstrap-select-plugin-not-working-with-time-consuming-page-load)).

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...display code
    setTimeout(function () {        
        $('#mySelect').selectpicker({
            container: 'body', 
            actionsBox: true,
            liveSearch: true,
            maxOptions: 16,
            noneSelectedText: 'Sites',
            selectedTextFormat: 'count>0'
        });

        ...more display code
    }, 100);
});
```

If I remove the setTimeout, the selectpicker displays with the options listed in the code, but if I leave the setTimeout, only the default options are used.  Does anyone know why this is the case and how to get it to use the correct options when called from within the setTimeout?

Comment: this is really strange... did you tried to initialize the plugin via data attributes?

Comment: silvio, I don't understand your question.  the initialization code is right there in my sample.  what do you mean by data attributes?

Comment: Here at the docs ( https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select#usage ) we say that if you use a 1.6.3 or newer, you don't need to do anything else, as the data-api automatically picks up the `<select>`s with the `.selectpicker` class.

Comment: I am using the most recent version, 1.10.0.  Sorry for not providing that earlier.  I am familiar with the documentation for this control and have used it successfully in other places that do not require a setTimeout.  As for the data attributes, I didn't realize what you meant at first, but I believe you mean putting the options directly on <select>.  That is not possible for us because one of the options is set dynamically at runtime (maxOptions is actually a calculated value that changes, but I simplified here since I can see in debug that it's value is 16).